# Woocommerce get_item() function returns false

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

With WooCommerce 3+ introducing new API to fetch the order and it's details, a lot of things have changed and many things break as well.

Consider the following code in my plugin:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$id= 27;

var_dump($order->get_item($id));
```

which gives me **bool(false)**. I have checked the database and the order and the item does exist.

Also

`var_dump($order)` does return the entire order object with all the items.

So basically, only the function `get_item` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only explanation is that the ID you are using is not an **`item_id`** with a type **`"line_item"`**…

I have tried and it works normally as expected using **`WC_Abstract_Order`** **`get_item()`** method when the **`item_id`** is of type "line_item".

To get and check the correct **`"line_item"`** Item IDs from a defined Order ID, try:

```
// define an exiting order ID first
$order_id = 422;

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
    $item_ids_array[] = $item_id;
}

var_dump( $item_ids_array ); // will output all item IDs (of type "line_item") for this order

## ==> Then now you can try (to check get_item() method):

foreach( $item_ids_array as $item_id ){
    var_dump( $order->get_item( $item_id ) ); //  Will output each WC_Order_Item_Product Object …
}
```

This should clarify things.

As reference: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)